# Bing static maps

Tags: google-maps, bing-maps

Since Google Static Maps imposes a daily quota on its service (and so does Google Maps JavaScript API unfortunately), I'm considering instead Microsoft's [Bing Static Maps API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701724.aspx). With Google it was enough to include on my website one line of code:

```
<img class="google_maps" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=48.2044544,16.3706368&zoom=9&markers=color:red%7Clabel:A%7C48.2044544,16.3706368&size=200x200&key=XXXXXXXXXXXX">
```

Bing's example code snippet

```
http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Imagery/Map/imagerySet/centerPoint/zoomLevel?mapSize=mapSize&pushpin=pushpin&mapLayer=mapLayer&format=format&mapMetadata=mapMetadata&key=BingMapsKey
```

seems to follow the same logic, but I couldn't get it to work. Has anybody experience

1. whether there is really no limit (in practice) for using the Bing Maps API
2. How to correctly include a bing map in my website?

Thank you!

Comment: For Google Maps, you should have enough quota per day already. You should try optimize your load and if you still do not have enough quota, you should consider purchasing a Google Maps API for Work license to get more quota.

Answer (score 0):

Full documentation on how to use the static Imagery service in Bing Maps can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701724.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I know it doesn't answer the main question, but the OP mentioned the reason he has the problem is because of the daily quota. So I came here to offer an free to use/self hosted alternative I made just to cincurvent that. It's sort of a clone of google static maps called osm-static-maps, you can find it here https://github.com/jperelli/osm-static-maps